# What is the difference between the mach headers in /usr/include and the ones in the SDK?

Tags: macos, mach

In MacOS X there are Mach kernel headers located both at

- `/usr/include/mach` and
- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/mach`

These headers do not match: they provide different APIs (functions, types, etc).

- What is the difference between them?
- When should I use which?

Comment: Are they different versions of the same SDK possibly?

Comment: One can check the headers of the SDKs for different SDK versions, and they vary slightly. However, when one compares those with the APIs in `/usr/include/mach`, the APIs are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation for the Kernel framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel):

> The Kernel Framework provides the APIs and support for kernel-resident device drivers and other kernel extensions.

If that's not what you're programming, then you shouldn't use it (including header files from it).

Comment: So I guess if I am using user-space applications I should use `/usr/include/mach` and if I am writing kernel extensions/device drivers then I should use the API in the SDK/Kernel folder right? This would make sense, because the APIs in the Kernel folder look like they allow doing things that user-space programs shouldn't be able to do .

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between them:

Firstly a bit of context to the usr folder:

**/usr**

Contains non-essential command-line binaries, libraries, header files, and other data that are not system critical (**meaning the system can reboot without needing these files**). This folder is a UNIX-specific directory which has been inherited by OS X.

**/usr/include**

The directory for 'header files' needed for compiling user space source code.

Type `man hier` in terminal, this will provide you with file system hierachy and a description for each directory.

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs**

The more recent versions of Xcode don’t use headers from "/usr/include/" anymore. Instead Xcode uses the headers from the SDKs embed in it's package.

> Why are they different?

This is because they are almost certainly different versions, both came from different installation sources so the chances that they will be the same is highly unlikely.

> When should I use which?

This answer does depend what you're trying to do?

You should use the Xcode package SDKs if you are developing in Xcode, otherwise use /usr/include/ if you're developing outside of Xcode.

Sources:

[Linux Exploring the File System](http://web.archive.org/web/20100511072431/http://bid.ankara.edu.tr/yardim/linux.install.guide/node116.html)

[Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html)

[Apple File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW14)

Comment: So what's the difference between both sets of `mach` headers ? What you mention boils down to the ones in the SDK being "system critical" and the ones in `/usr/include` being "not system critical", but that does not really tell me anything because you haven't mentioned what "system critical" means.

Comment: Also, if I am not developing in Xcode, should I still use the SDK headers or should I use the ones in `/usr/include` ? And why? It might help me to understand if I knew "how" and "why" these headers are different. I don't even know why they are different at all.

Comment: @gnzlbg see my updated answer, also I think you've gotten confused - none of these SDKs are system critical - meaning the system (OS X) can still reboot without them but they are needed by the C compilers.

Comment: @gnzlbg also what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am writing an user-space application that needs to use mach kernel calls. I am not programming using the Xcode IDE. I just use the `clang` compiler directly.

Comment: "You should use the Xcode package SDKs if you are developing in Xcode, otherwise use /usr/include/ if you're developing outside of Xcode." Do you have a source for this, or how do you know? Xcode programs are userspace applications.

Comment: "This is because they are almost certainly different versions, " This is unlikely, given that the differences are more like the types of operations that are permitted at all. Some things that one of the headers allow can probably only for privileged-mode programs, or parts of the mach kernel.

Comment: If you install the command line tools it should install updated headers for you, or you can use xcrun --sdk macosx clang to invoke clang and it will automatically use the headers inside the SDK.